# Measurability of cartesian product wrt. product-$\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)$ be measurable spaces, and define on $X \times Y$ the the product algebra
$$
\mathcal{F} = \sigma (\{A \times B : A \in \mathcal{F}_X,B\in \mathcal{F}_Y\})
$$

Now, if $V \times W \subset X \times Y$ has both $V \in \mathcal{F}_X$ and $W \in \mathcal{F}_Y$ then obviously $V \times W \in \mathcal{F}$. However, I was wondering if we have $V \in \mathcal{F}_X$ but $W \notin \mathcal{F}_Y$, can we then conclude that $V \times W \notin \mathcal{F}$? Any further conditions on the underlying spaces we can impose to be able to conclude that $V\times W$ is not measurable?

Comment: Yes, and this is part of  the proof of Fubini's Theorem in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: Your statement is true if you assume that $V \neq \emptyset$.